# Android DatePicker dialog not showing on Android 6

Tags: android, dialog

I have a DatePicker in my app that has always worked on both phones and tablets until Android 6. I have a Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge t test on and the dialog is not showing.

I have set the min and target sdk version to 11 and 21 respectively in the manifest.

I understand that i should be using DialogFragment but is there a reason why the code below is not showing on Android 6? The code works fine on 2.3.6, 4.x and 5.x.

The following log is being executed so i know that the .show() method has been called.

```
Log.e(TAG, "Just executed dialog.show() and at the end of showDateTimeDialog method");
```

[EDIT]
Things i have tried are :

Adding a style to the style.xml and the calling a different Dialog constuctor that references that style. This does show a dialog on Android 6, but unfortunately it is not my custom one that uses the my layout with buttons on.

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

.

```
dialog = new Dialog(MenuActivity2.this, R.style.MyDialogStyle);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datetimepickerunalloc);
```

Thanks

```
Button Set;
    Button ReSet;
    Button Cancel;
    DatePicker DPic;

    TextView Date;
    private ViewSwitcher switcher;
    static final int DATE_TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    Dialog dialog;
    TextView dialogMessage;
    DateTime timeSetOnSpinner;

    public void showDateTimeDialog() {



        // final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        final SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");

        dialog = new Dialog(MenuActivity2.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datetimepickerunalloc);



        DPic = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.DatePicker);





        Set = ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime));
        Set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(DPic.getYear(), DPic.getMonth(), DPic.getDayOfMonth());

                timeSetOnSpinner = new DateTime(c);

                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
                String formattedDate = fmt.print(timeSetOnSpinner);
                formattedDate = formattedDate.trim();

                //Toast.makeText(MenuActivity2.this, "date = " + formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                final Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity2.this, ShowUnallocatedCallsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("unallocdate", formattedDate);
                startActivity(intent);


            }// end of onClick
        });

        ReSet = ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ResetDateTime));
        ReSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                DPic.updateDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            }
        });


         dialog.setTitle("Unallocated calls date");

        try {
            ReSet.performClick();
            dialog.show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Just executed dialog.show() and at the end of showDateTimeDialog method");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }

    }// showDateTimeDialog()
```

.

This is my layout for the custom dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewdatetimepickermessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"


         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DateLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

                <DatePicker
                    android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ControlButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/SetDateTime"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@android:string/ok" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ResetDateTime"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Reset" />

        <!--
                                 <Button 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_width="0dip" 
                                android:id="@+id/CancelDialog" 
                                android:text="@android:string/cancel" 
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

.

Comment: can you print the stack trace instead of // ignore in the catch of dialog.show(); and see if an exception is fired on Android 6

Comment: @androidLover Hi, i've posted the stacktrace with the try/catch removed. There is no exception thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got the dialog showing by using a different constructor that passed in a theme arg.

```
dialog = new Dialog(MenuActivity2.this, R.style.AppBaseTheme );
```

Comment: HI, I have a similar use case.  Can you post the theme that you used in styles.xml?